# Ansible with_items keeps overwriting last line of loop

Tags: cron, ansible

This is my playbook. Pretty simple. The problem is with the "with_items". It iterates over all the items, but, it only writes the last item to the crontab file. I think it is overwriting it. Why is this happening?

```
- name: Create cron jobs to send emails                                       
  cron:                                                                                        
    name="Send emails"                                                          
    state=present                                                                              
    special_time=daily                                                                         
    job="/home/testuser/deployments/{{ item }}/artisan --env={{
item }} send:healthemail"                                                                 
  with_items:
      - london 
      - toronto
      - vancouver
```

Answer (score 21, accepted):

The `cron` module expects the job name to be unique. Change it to:

```
name="Send emails {{ item }}"
```

See: [cron – Manage cron.d and crontab entries](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/cron_module.html)